# Laravel 4 - public directory being treated as a route - image not showing

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4

I have this problem with Laravel 4's view. The code in view.blade.php is:

```
{{ HTML::image("public/images/storage/$user_upload->image.jpg") }}
```

which yields

```
http://dev.local/public/images/storage/1_thy9WFfBw.jpg
```

That is the correct image location, yet as being accessed by the framework, it turns out to be not accessible (i.e. HttpNotFound exception thrown). See screenshot: http://imgur.com/kKLu30L

I think the framework somehow treats this URL as a route resource rather than a public asset.

Is there anyway I could work this out?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this instead:

```
{{ HTML::image(asset('images/storage/' . $user_upload->image . '.jpg')) }}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
{{ HTML::image("images/storage/$val->user_upload".".jpg", $alt="not found") }}
```

If you are not still getting remove the .".jpg" extension because you might be storing file with extension