# Can't access Laravel /public anymore. Laravel handles it as a route.

Tags: php, laravel-5.3

In DirectAdmin, I have changed the domainname of my project. But unfortunately it did not gave me the result I was looking for. So I undid my action. But, that did not solve the problem.

At first, I was able to access my site.com/public folder to use the assets for my website. But after my failure Laravel handles the /public directory as a route. So, I dan't have access anymore to my public folder and needed assets.

My domain: good2beout.nl

Can anyone help me?

P.s. I already looked at question [Laravel 4 - public directory being treated as a route - image not showing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23355289/laravel-4-public-directory-being-treated-as-a-route-image-not-showing) but this does not solve my problem.

Comment: Did you updated your APP_URL in your .env file?

Comment: @FelippeDuarte Don't have APP_URL in my .env file

Comment: And in your config/app.php, do you have a 'url' key? Try update that info.

Comment: In my config/app.php i have 'url' => 'http://good2beout.nl/',
(Looks good, I think)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found my problem.

I accidentally overwrote my .htaccess file, replaced it with

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]
```

https://laravel.com/docs/4.2#pretty-urls